# interactive web page for differential calculus

Tags: calculus, technology-in-education, interactive-teaching

I apologize if this is a silly question.

I look for free online web page for a ***differential calculus*** and theirs ***rules*** for higher school. By google shearch, I don't have an intersting results. For instance:

http://www.sporcle.com/games/14111184/calculus

The french pages gives more famous things.
Thank's for any help!

Comment: How about [http://calculusapplets.com](http://calculusapplets.com)?

Comment: After dowloding this file I have no response. it does'nt work

Comment: It is a webpage of links to Java applets. You will need a browser that runs applets, and you will need to give it the correct permissions.

Comment: http://wolframalpha.com will give you the derivatives, but not necessarily the rules used to obtain those derivatives

Answer (score 2):

Jim Fowler, Bart Snapp, and I collaborated on a project called "Mooculus".

The main page is here:  https://mooculus.osu.edu/

There is a free open source textbook (mostly Bart), youtube "lecture" videos (mostly Jim), and Khan Academy style practice exercises (mostly me).

Here are some highlights from the interactive stuff.  Note that you have to log in with a google account for any of this to work unfortunately.

1. https://mooculus.osu.edu/explorations/derivative

   This let's a student enter any elementary function, and we algorithmically compute the derivative step by step, while citing the appropriate derivative rule.
2. https://mooculus.osu.edu/exercises/tangentLineIdea

Forces the student to graph a tangent line to a function

3. https://mooculus.osu.edu/exercises/derivativeOracle

Gives student access to a "black box" function, and asks them to approximate the derivative

There are many more for you to explore on the webpage. For instance, chain rule problems with tables, problems where they have to differentiate an arbitrary elementary function (we have an expression input), problems that force them to think about derivatives of inverse functions geometrically, etc. We have not done much maintenance, so there may be some bugs (I think, sadly, a mathjax update killed some of our multiple choice questions, for instance).